Задание в вузе: нужно найти два горячих TRX адреса биржи , которые нигде не размечены
дали такое задание. Условие. Криптовалютная биржа Bynex. В интернете есть обозреватели, на которых можно найти ее горячие адреса в криптовалюте TRX. но помимо размеченных адресов есть и неизвестные. Нужно найти минимум два горячих адреса, которые нигде не размечены.
Я начал решать так.
Перешел в https://www.oklink.com/ru/trx и ввел Bynex.
Нашел там две транзакции.
T9yD14Nj9j7xAB4dbGeiX9h8unkKHxuWwb (является горячим адресом, но не понятно, имеет ли он отношение к этой бирже)
THZeuY2J4Tq4tq5ahDbQrg5SnhxSJqqutw
Я проанализировал кошелек THZeuY2J4Tq4tq5ahDbQrg5SnhxSJqqutw. Нашел транзакции, которые присылали на этот кошелек с TQAawVyuA4dv966CuxqqxidWEpqSrwgTqp. Уже этот кошелек является горячим, там много очень транзакций было, но кошелек уже не действующий.
Дальше я ничего не нашел.
Преподаватель дал подсказку: что я нашел один горячий адрес. Дал последнюю попытку и подсказку: первый адрес сейчас перестал выполнять функцию горячего и его сменил новый, который и нужно найти.
Сможете помочь? Ответьте, по итогу, какие два кошелька являются горячими адресами? Или подскажите, как решать такие задачи, заранее спасибо вам.
